# Hashicorp vault performance issue on concurrent load

Tags: performance, concurrency, aws-lambda, hashicorp-vault

We are using Hashicorp vault to store the Database secrets. Our application is based on AWS Lambda microservices.
Whenever there is burst in traffic and all the Lambda services are trying to get database secrets from vault simultaneously, vault is taking huge amount of time(~20 secs) to return the secret.
How can I fix this issue ? Doesn't Vault have concurrency support ?

Comment: Performance of Vault depends directly on the performance of backend used. What is the backed used for Vault? Is it Consul?? How many Consul servers do you have? What is the consistency level set to for Consul servers?

Comment: Dynamo DB is being used as backend storage and that's running in HA mode already